# How do dcast a pandas dataframe and then map the column names when dropping the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
       df = pd.DataFrame({'fmc': [1, 2],
                       'id_r': [1, 1],
                       'id_b': ['a', 'b'],
                       'id_c': ['br', 'br'],
                       'fmc_': ['aa_bb', 'cc_dd']})
```

I would like to `dcast` this `df` with `index=['id_r', 'id_b', 'id_c']` and `values='fmc'`.

I would like the output to be like

```
import numpy as np
        dff = pd.DataFrame({'id_r': [1, 1],
                      'id_b': ['a', 'b'],
                      'id_c': ['br', 'br'],
                      'fmc_aa_bb':[1, np.nan],
                      'fmc_cc_dd':[np.nan, 2]})
```

I followed a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589125/how-to-dcast-in-pandas-with-more-than-one-columns-for-columns-argument) of mine

```
  df = df.pivot_table(index=['id_r', 'id_b', 'id_c'], columns='fmc_', values='fmc')
        df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
        df = df.reset_index()
```

But does not give the desired output.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code with `add_prefix`

```
s=df.pivot_table(index=['id_r', 'id_b', 'id_c'], columns='fmc_', values='fmc').add_prefix('fmc_').reset_index()
Out[190]: 
fmc_  id_r id_b id_c  fmc_aa_bb  fmc_cc_dd
0        1    a   br        1.0        NaN
1        1    b   br        NaN        2.0
```

Comment: Thank you ! What is this `fmc_` column at the beginning ?

Comment: @quantq that is column name , you can do rename_axis(None)

Comment: Adding it to the end ? like `df.pivot_table(index=['id_r', 'id_b', 'id_c'], columns='fmc_', values='fmc').add_prefix('fmc_').reset_index().rename_axis(None)` ? because this gives the same result

Comment: @quant `df.pivot_table(index=['id_r', 'id_b', 'id_c'], columns='fmc_', values='fmc').add_prefix('fmc_').reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
`